# Posts Being Uploaded Randomly in Collection View - Swift & Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have been refactoring my code and now I'm having trouble with the posts.

Whenever I add a **new post to the collection view**, it is being **added in a random cell and out of order**, instead of in the first post.

I know the **reason is the fetchuser function** and from what I'm being told due to the asynchronous loading, but don't know what to do in order to correct this.

Could someone help me figure out what to do so that my posts are added in the first cell?

```
 @objc func observePostsAdoption() {
    let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "postType").queryEqual(toValue: "adopt").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        var tempPost = [Posts]()
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot {
                let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String: Any]
                let newAdoptiondPost = Posts.transformPost(dict: dict!)
                //This will look up all users at once
                self.fetchUser(userid: newAdoptiondPost.userid!, completed: {
                 tempPost.insert(newAdoptiondPost, at: 0)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.postsadoption = tempPost
                        self.adoptionCollectionView.reloadData()
                        self.refresherAdoption.endRefreshing()
                    }
            })
            }

        }
    }
}

func fetchUser(userid: String, completed:  @escaping ()-> Void ) {

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let user = UserProfile.transformUser(dict: dict)
            self.users.insert(user, at: 0)
            completed()
        }
    }

}
```

Here's my Post Struct

```
class Posts {

//UserView
var uid: String?
var author: UserProfile?
var timestamp: Date?
var userid: String?

func getDateFormattedString() -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, HH:mm"
    return formatter.string(from: self.timestamp!)
}

//Image
var photoUrl: URL?

//PostInformation View
var city: String?
var municipality: String?
var name: String?
var breed : String?
var phone : String?
var address : String?
var petType: String?
var genderType: String?
var comments: String?
```

}

extension Posts {

```
static func transformPost(dict: [String: Any]) -> Posts {

    let post = Posts()

    //Post Picture
    let photoUrl = dict["photoUrl"] as? String
    post.photoUrl = URL(string: photoUrl!)

    //INFO POSTS
    post.userid = dict["userid"] as? String
    post.city = dict["city"] as? String
    post.municipality = dict["municipality"] as? String
    post.name = dict["name"] as? String
    post.breed = dict["breed"] as? String
    post.phone = dict["phone"] as? String
    post.address = dict["address"] as? String
    post.comments = dict["comments"] as? String
    post.petType = dict["petType"] as? String
    post.genderType = dict["gender"] as? String
    let timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double
    post.timestamp = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp!/1000)

    return post

}
```

}

Comment: If your Post object has a property such as timestamp it will be very easy to do sorting. Can you show your Posts struct?

Comment: Hey Galo! I've added it to the question.

Comment: Also, the thing is that I need to sort by "postType" for in this case adoption, because I have several other postTypes such as lost and found. Can I sort by the two different types? Timestamp AND postType?

Comment: What exactly do you mean postType? I don't see any property where the postType is set.

Comment: Check in the first function. The observePostsAdoption. The postType is in Firebase --> let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "postType").queryEqual(toValue: "adopt").observe(.value)

Comment: Oh ok. I should have explained better. Sorting should be happening at the client side since Firebase is async. So you will need to have the property in your post object. Otherwise you will have to do it using dispatch groups instead of dispatch async.

Comment: Hi Galo, I am a newbie in swift, could you further explain what I would have to do in the "You will need to have the property in your post object"? Is it complicated?

Comment: Not at all. Variables in a struct are called properties. For exam ample “petType” is a property that you set in the struct. So it is just adding a “postType” variable in your Post struct. I’ll post an answer later showing you how to do sorting by both postType and tinestamp

Comment: Hi Galo! Thanks a lot, but I still have the doubt if it can be sorted by both variables? The "postType" and the timestamp? Because I have three collection views, each displaying the postType, (lost,found, adoption) so that sorting is a must in this case :/

Comment: I guess I am bit confused with your question then. You want to populate 3 different collectionViews, each depending of the postType, and the sorting that you want is how? If you have 3 collectionViews and each displays the different portTypes then it is quite easy to just populate them from the arrays that you must have. Am I missing something? In other words, how do you want the posts to appear? ordered by date, name....??

Comment: Yes that's correct. I have already sorted all the posts depending on postType. As I mentioned in the question, the problem is that they are not being loading in order. Previously, before the fetchUser() function, it was working correctly. I was being putting the most recently added posts into the first cell with --   tempPost.insert(newAdoptiondPost, at: 0) -- but it's not working. When a user now adds a post, it gets added randomly into a cell. That's the doubt. Why are new posts NOT being added to the first cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the posts ordered by post type you can just do sorting depending on the timestamp. For example

```
@objc func observePostsAdoption() {
        let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
        postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "postType").queryEqual(toValue: "adopt").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            var tempPost = [Posts]()
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot {
                    let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String: Any]
                    let newAdoptiondPost = Posts.transformPost(dict: dict!)
                    //This will look up all users at once
                    self.fetchUser(userid: newAdoptiondPost.userid!, completed: {
                        tempPost.insert(newAdoptiondPost, at: 0)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.postsadoption = tempPost
                            self.postsadoption.sort { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                                return p1.timeStamp?.compare(p2.timeStamp!) == .orderdDescending
                            }
                            self.adoptionCollectionView.reloadData()
                            self.refresherAdoption.endRefreshing()
                        }
                    })
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

With that the posts adoption array will be sorted depending on the timestamp that you have.